# MySQL Query selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big database table called *pricing*. The fields are following:

> id code description rrp buy stock date distributor vendor version

User select the ***vendor*** field only. ***version*** field can be vary for each distributor. I need to display all the details from **pricing** table but only the recent version of each distributor. For that I am trying to get all distributors and it's recent version. I have coded as below:

```
$all_distributors=mysql_query("SELECT `distributor`,MAX(`version`) as `version` FROM `pricing` WHERE `vendor`='$vendor_id' GROUP BY `distributor`,`version`",$con);
while($all_dist= mysql_fetch_array($all_distributors))
{
    $d_ID=$all_dist['distributor'];
    $d_version=$all_dist['version'];
    echo $d_ID."-".$d_version."<br/>";
}
```

But the output shows all versions of distributors, like below:

```
distributor-version
1-20131107V1
1-20131108V2
2-20131108V1
```

How can I display only the latest version of each distributor?

So the output should be:

```
1-20131108V2
2-20131108V1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grouping by `distributor, version` makes it so that any unique combo of distributor and version is a separate group. This is what is being displayed in your output. I think you only want to group by `distributor` if I'm reading the question right.

Comment: huh! that's correct. Thanks! I have been thinking other ways..you saved my day :)